# How to convert an image to URL Discord Py

Tags: python, discord.py

If there any way to convert an image to an Url?

Like, if "x" admin do a `!Warn Simplezes Reason` (Reason should be a text accompanied by an image that the admin will send)
when the admin send the command, the bot should display something like `Simplezes has been warned. Reason:` and show an URL to the picture that the admin sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discord.py you've an attribute to the Message object that called "attachments", it's a list of all the attachments of the message ("Attachment" class [[DISCORD.PY DOCS]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment)).

Now we know that this attribute contains a list of "Attachment" class.
The "Attachment" class have an attribute called "url" and that's the url of the attachment.

That what you was looking for ^^, now for example you can do:

```
for attachment in message.attachments:
    # Do what you want with attachment.url
    print(attachment.url)
```

I recommend you also to save the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

And join to discord.py discord server for fast response on your questions related to discord.py!